# Slow transfers in Jetty with chunked transfer encoding at certain buffer size

Tags: java, hadoop, jetty

I'm investigating a performance problem with Jetty 6.1.26. Jetty appears to use `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, and depending on the buffer size used, this can be very slow when transferring locally.

I've created a small Jetty test application with a single servlet that demonstrates the issue.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.mortbay.jetty.Server;
import org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector;
import org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context;

public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final int bufferSize = 65536;
        resp.setBufferSize(bufferSize);
        OutputStream outStream = resp.getOutputStream();

        FileInputStream stream = null;
        try {
            stream = new FileInputStream(new File("test.data"));
            int bytesRead;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            while( (bytesRead = stream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0 ) {
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                outStream.flush();
            }
        } finally   {
            if( stream != null )
                stream.close();
            outStream.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server();
        SelectChannelConnector ret = new SelectChannelConnector();
        ret.setLowResourceMaxIdleTime(10000);
        ret.setAcceptQueueSize(128);
        ret.setResolveNames(false);
        ret.setUseDirectBuffers(false);
        ret.setHost("0.0.0.0");
        ret.setPort(8080);
        server.addConnector(ret);
        Context context = new Context();
        context.setDisplayName("WebAppsContext");
        context.setContextPath("/");
        server.addHandler(context);
        context.addServlet(TestServlet.class, "/test");
        server.start();
    }

}
```

In my experiment, I'm using a 128MB test file that the servlet returns to the client, which connects using localhost. Downloading this data using a simple test client written in Java (using `URLConnection`) takes 3.8 seconds, which is very slow (yes, it's 33MB/s, which doesn't sound slow, except that this is purely local and the input file was cached; it should be much faster).

Now here's where it gets strange. If I download the data with wget, which is a HTTP/1.0 client and therefore doesn't support chunked transfer encoding, it only takes 0.1 seconds. That's a much better figure.

Now when I change `bufferSize` to 4096, the Java client takes 0.3 seconds.

If I remove the call to `resp.setBufferSize` entirely (which appears to use a 24KB chunk size), the Java client now takes 7.1 seconds, and wget is suddenly equally slow!

Please note I'm not in any way an expert with Jetty. I stumbled across this problem while diagnosing a performance problem in Hadoop 0.20.203.0 with reduce task shuffling, which transfers files using Jetty in a manner much like the reduced sample code, with a 64KB buffer size.

The problem reproduces both on our Linux (Debian) servers and on my Windows machine, and with both Java 1.6 and 1.7, so it appears to depend solely on Jetty.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this, and if there's something I can do about it?

Comment: +1. I have also observed this. But didn't really get a good solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe I have found the answer myself, by looking through the Jetty source code. It's actually a complex interplay of the response buffer size, the size of the buffer passed to `outStream.write`, and whether or not `outStream.flush` is called (in some situations). The issue is with the way Jetty uses its internal response buffer, and how the data you write to the output is copied to that buffer, and when and how that buffer is flushed.

If the size of the buffer used with `outStream.write` is equal to the response buffer (I think a multiple also works), or less and `outStream.flush` is used, then performance is fine. Each `write` call is then flushed straight to the output, which is fine. However, when the write buffer is larger and not a multiple of the response buffer, this seems to cause some weirdness in how the flushes are handled, causing extra flushes, leading to bad performance.

In the case of chunked transfer encoding, there's an extra kink in the cable. For all but the first chunk, Jetty reserves 12 bytes of the response buffer to contain the chunk size. This means that in my original example with a 64KB write and response buffer, the actual amount of data that fit in the response buffer was only 65524 bytes, so again, parts of the write buffer were spilling into multiple flushes. Looking at a captured network trace of this scenario, I see that the first chunk is 64KB, but all subsequent chunks are 65524 bytes. In this case, `outStream.flush` makes no difference.

When using a 4KB buffer I was seeing fast speeds only when `outStream.flush` was called. It turns out that `resp.setBufferSize` will only increase the buffer size, and since the default size is 24KB, `resp.setBufferSize(4096)` is a no-op. However, I was now writing 4KB pieces of data, which fit in the 24KB buffer even with the reserved 12 bytes, and are then flushed as a 4KB chunk by the `outStream.flush` call. However, when the call to `flush` is removed, it will let the buffer fill up, again with 12 bytes spilling into the next chunk because 24 is a multiple of 4.

### In conclusion

It seems that to get good performance with Jetty, you must either:

- When calling `setContentLength` (no chunked transfer encoding) and use a buffer for `write` that's the same size as the response buffer size.
- When using chunked transfer encoding, use a write buffer that's at least 12 bytes smaller than the response buffer size, and call `flush` after each write.

Note that the performance of the "slow" scenario is still such that you'll likely only see the difference on the local host or very fast (1Gbps or more) network connection.

I guess I should file issue reports against Hadoop and/or Jetty for this.

Comment: I doubt you find anyone in the jetty team that is particularly responsive to a bug report on Jetty 6. But if the same issue exists in  Jetty 7 or 8, then a bug report would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Jetty will default to `Transfer-Encoding: Chunked` if the size of response cannot be determined.

If you know the size of response that what its going to be.
You need to call `resp.setContentLength(135*1000*1000*1000);` in this case instead of

`resp.setBufferSize();`

actually setting resp.setBufferSize is immaterial.

Before opening the OutputStream, that is before this line:
`OutputStream outStream = resp.getOutputStream();`
you need to call
`resp.setContentLength(135*1000*1000*1000);`

(the line above)

Give it a spin. see if that works.
Those are my guesses from theory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `resp.setContentLength` without `resp.setBufferSize` is still slow. However, with `resp.setContentLength` both buffer sizes I tried (64KB and 4KB) are now fast. Also see the update to the question.

Comment: Actually, it appears that the default buffer size is fast if and only if the size of the buffer passed to `outStream.write` is less than 24KB (the default response buffer size).

Comment: forgot that i commented the flush above in case of no chunking (setting content-lenght)

Comment: how can i make Jetty to refuse using Transfer-Encoding:Chunked by default. Some some client are ancient and they require 'Content-Length' header in response

Answer (score 0):

This is pure speculation, but I'm guessing this is some sort of Garbage Collector issue.  Does the performance of the Java client improve when you run the JVM with more heap like...
    java -Xmx 128m

I don't recall the JVM switch to turn on GC logging, but figure that out and see if GC kicks in just as you are getting into your doGet.

My 2 cents.

Comment: On second thought...128m seems to be the default.  So my suggestion isn't going to help.  I'll be downvoted into oblivion.  Oh the humanity.

Comment: These guys say that managing buffer size on your own may not be such a great idea:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638974/what-is-the-buffer-size-in-bufferedreader

Comment: Yet using the default buffer size on the `HttpServletResponse` actually gave me the worst performance.