# Setting socket send buffer size on Tomcat/Jetty

Tags: sockets, tomcat, jetty

Is there a way I can set the send buffer size for the HTTP listener/response sockets created by Tomcat or Jetty? (ie. SO_SNDBUF). Apologies if I'm getting the terminology wrong.

**Update:**

After googling around and with @Joakim's help I found this:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_Connectors

and

[Slow transfers in Jetty with chunked transfer encoding at certain buffer size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031311/slow-transfers-in-jetty-with-chunked-transfer-encoding-at-certain-buffer-size)

The question then is are the "buffer size" referred by the Jetty.xml config as well as the HttpServletResponse.setBufferSize() the same as the socket "send buffer size"?

**Update 2:**

Reading more I think neither affect the socket buffer size and its just another buffer the servlet container uses before sending it over to the Socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jetty has no support for Socket.setSendBufferSize() in any version of Jetty.

You can however, provide your own implementation of a [Connector](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Connector.html) to do just that.

Start by extending [SocketConnector](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/bio/SocketConnector.html) in which you provide your own [.configure(Socket)](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/AbstractConnector.html#configure%28java.net.Socket%29) implementation that does [Socket.setSendBufferSize(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getSendBufferSize%28%29).

Comment: Thanks Joakim! Does this allow me to replace the HTTP listener that Jetty uses with my own implementation of the Connector?

Comment: It sure would, you can be as complicated as you want to.  Start with looking at the open source code for the various connectors to see what will best suit your needs.

Comment: Much appreciated @Joakim. Searching on Google, would this be the method to replace the default connector with my own implementation? http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-connectors.html

Comment: You linked to Jetty 9 documentation (currently in Milestones/Beta's), a far more complicated beast.  Where we have to contend with TLS/SPDY/WebSocket/HTTP2.0 protocol upgrade/negotiation issues.  Jetty 9 also has no blocking socket implementation anymore.  Simply setting the Socket.setSendBufferSize() on all accepted sockets could (maybe) be problematic as you don't (yet) know what the protocol is.  Try out what you want with Jetty 7 or 8 (stable/mature) to see if you really want that feature.

Answer (score 1):

In Jetty 9 with spring it can be done with:

```
@Configuration
```

public class CustomJettyConfiguration {

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer customizer() {
    return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {

        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
            if (container instanceof JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
                customizeJetty((JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container);
            }
        }

        private void customizeJetty(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory jetty) {
            jetty.addServerCustomizers(new JettyServerCustomizer() {

                @Override
                public void customize(Server server) {
                    for (Connector connector : server.getConnectors()) {
                        if (connector instanceof ServerConnector) {
                            HttpConnectionFactory connectionFactory = ((ServerConnector) connector)
                                    .getConnectionFactory(HttpConnectionFactory.class);
                            connectionFactory.getHttpConfiguration()
                                    .setResponseHeaderSize(16 * 1024);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };

}
```

}