# Java putting Hashmap into Treemap

Tags: java, hashmap, treemap

I am currently reading 2 million lines from a textfile as asked in the previous question
[Java Fastest way to read through text file with 2 million lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486077/java-fastest-way-to-read-through-text-file-with-2-million-lines)

Now I store these information into HashMap and I want to sort it via TreeMap because I want to use ceilingkey. Is the following method correct?

```
private HashMap<Integer, String> hMap = new HashMap();

private TreeMap<Integer, String> tMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>(hMap);
```

Comment: `Collections.sort(hMap)`  ? ,`Collections.sort(hMap,WITH_MY_OWN_COMPARATOR)`  ?

Comment: Why not just put it directly into a `TreeMap` ? Why the extra step?

Comment: hrm...i still prefer to sort it with treemap but as of my code, the treemap is empty

Comment: @suresh atta : `Collections.sort(hMap)` won't work, `sort()` work with List only

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
HashMap<Integer, String> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
TreeMap<Integer, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
treeMap.putAll(hashMap);
```

Should work anyway.

Comment: Are you just kidding ??? [Passing constructor also calls](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeMap.java#TreeMap.%3Cinit%3E%28java.util.Map%29) `putAll()` :). Checkout the source code link, I added

Comment: @user2822351 I'm not telling that this answer is wrong, What I'm telling is this answer is equals to what you are doing right now.

Comment: It's correct, but the usage of the constructor is more elegant.

Comment: @user2822351The question is... is it any different from what you have posted in ur question above !?

Comment: @ Akkusativobjekt, i am using constructor but it doesnt work. the treemap is empty when i try to print out

Comment: Then that is the problem, Post your full code. A simple test would be print the original map and then print tree map and see for difference.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ oh gosh i manage to solve it, because the hashmap is added at runtime, so i have to construct it after i have added to the hashmap

Comment: @user2822351 Ooops.Happens some time. Good catch. I'l be happy If you delete this post :)

Answer (score 6):

This would work just fine:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
TreeMap<Integer, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<>(hashMap);
```

But I wouldn't advise using `HashMap` to store the input. You end up with two Maps holding the same huge data. Either do it on the fly and add directly into `TreeMap` or use `List` to `TreeMap` conversion.

Also, for even more efficiency consider [primitive collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307622/most-efficient-java-primitive-collections-library).

Answer (score 2):

```
HashMap<Integer, String> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
TreeMap<Integer, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
hashMap.remove(null);
treeMap.putAll(hashMap);
```

HashMap will allow null but TreeMap not so before adding into Treemap, remove null from keyset