# How to convert HashMap to TreeMap

Tags: java, hashmap, treemap

This question seems to be very popular and yet I couldn't get correct results for my implementation. I had this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512850/java-putting-hashmap-into-treemap) as an example but so far no luck.

Here I have HashMap that I need to convert to TreeMap in order to have key values sorted:

```
HasMap<String, HashMap<String, SomeBean>> hashMap = (HashMap<String, HashMap<String, SomeBean>>)request.getAttribute("HASHMAP");
```

After applying iterator I could see results in unsorted order.

Now I want to convert it to TreeMap:

```
TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, SomeBean>> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, SomeBean>>(hashMap);
```

Result:

```
The constructor TreeMap<String,TreeMap<String,SomeBean>>(HashMap<String,HashMap<String,SomeBean>>) is undefined
```

Well, it seems because i have nested map with my bean class it is not allowing me to create  new tree map. It is understandable as I don't expect TreeMap to have constructor that suits my criteria but the question is how do I find workaround for this problem?

Comment: does the nested class have to be a specific `HashMap` or `TreeMap`, or can it be the common interface `Map`?

Comment: Did you try treeMap.putAll(hashMap); ? https://repl.it/GZO1/0

Comment: @nandsito backend has it as HashMap and passes to front as an attribute, if I change backend it is better change it to TreeMap then, I just didn't want to touch backend as it was already developed by another developer, was trying to find solution in jsp page.

Comment: @K.S I did, it works if you have primitive value or String  as parameters but as I said if I have nested map with my bean class it gives me error.

Answer (score 1):

Since your maps have incompatible value types, you'll need to convert them manually:

```
    Map<String, Map<String, SomeBean>> treeMap = new TreeMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> e : hashMap.entrySet())
        treeMap.put(e.getKey(), new TreeMap<>(e.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code uses the nested map as a regular `Map`, i.e. it doesn't use any specific method defined in `HashMap` or `TreeMap`, you can define the type parameter of your variables using `Map` instead:

```java
HashMap<String, Map<String, SomeBean>> hashMap =
    (HashMap<String, Map<String, SomeBean>>) request.getAttribute("HASHMAP");

TreeMap<String, Map<String, SomeBean>> treeMap =
    new TreeMap<String, Map<String, SomeBean>>(hashMap);
```

Or else, you won't be able to use `constructor(Map)` or `putAll(Map)`, and you will have to fill in the `treeMap` manually.