# HashMap to TreeMap

Tags: java, hashmap, converters, treemap

I am using `TreeMap` to sort the keys in the `Map`.

```
Map<Byte, List<TagEntity>> hashMap = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TagEntity::getTagType));

Map<Byte, List<TagEntity>> treeMap = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

But how to convert `HashMap` to `TreeMap`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the `TreeMap` directly by passing a map supplier to `groupingBy`:

```
Map<Byte, List<TagEntity>> treeMap = 
    list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TagEntity::getTagType,
                                      () -> new TreeMap<Byte, List<TagEntity>>(Comparator.reverseOrder()),
                                      Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can create hashmap to treemap:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
TreeMap<Integer, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
treeMap.putAll(hashMap);
```

Refer here [java-putting-hashmap-into-treemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512850/java-putting-hashmap-into-treemap?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

> TreeMap treeMap = new TreeMap<>(hashMap);

Or:

> treeMap.putAll(hashMap);

Comment: Using `new TreeMap<>(hashMap)` doesn't allow you to pass a `Comparator`.