# Read txt-files to mySQL database faster in Java

Tags: java, mysql, performance, readfile, text-parsing

I'm trying to read over 17 000 files (each file contains from 100 to 23 000 rows) and parse the data into a mysql database. The problem is that it is doing this too slow, and I don't know where the bottle neck is.

```
private void readFile() { 
    PreparedStatement prepStatement = null;

    String queryInsItem = "INSERT IGNORE INTO item VALUES(?)";

    String queryInsUser = "INSERT IGNORE INTO user VALUES(?)";

    String queryInsRating = "INSERT IGNORE INTO rating VALUES(?,?,?,?)";

    try {
        int x = 1;
        int itemID = 0;
        int userID = 0;
        int rating = 0;
        java.util.Date date = null;
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = null;
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String line = null;

        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("Loading...");
          File dir = new File("src/bigdata/training_set/");
          File[] directoryListing = dir.listFiles();
          if (directoryListing != null) {
            for (File itemFile : directoryListing) {
                in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(itemFile));
                line = in.readLine();
                itemID = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, line.length()-1));
                userID = 0;
                rating = 0;
                date = null;
                sqlDate = null;

                // Add to item table
                prepStatement = conn.prepareStatement(queryInsItem);
                prepStatement.setInt(1, itemID);
                prepStatement.executeUpdate();
                conn.commit();
                prepStatement.close();


                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Splits the line to corresponding variables
                    userID = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(",")));
                    rating = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(line.indexOf(",")+1, line.lastIndexOf(",")));
                    date= dateFormat.parse(line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(",")+1, line.length()));

                    sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());

                    // Add to user table
                    prepStatement = conn.prepareStatement(queryInsUser);
                    prepStatement.setInt(1, userID);
                    prepStatement.executeUpdate();
                    conn.commit();
                    prepStatement.close();

                    // Add to rating table
                    prepStatement = conn.prepareStatement(queryInsRating);
                    prepStatement.setInt(1, userID);
                    prepStatement.setInt(2, itemID);
                    prepStatement.setInt(3, rating);
                    prepStatement.setDate(4, sqlDate);
                    prepStatement.executeUpdate();
                    conn.commit();
                    prepStatement.close();

                }
                in.close();
                System.out.println("File " + x++ +" done.");
            }
          }


    } catch (IOException | ParseException | SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    System.out.println("Done.");
}
```

I've tried to str.split the lines first and then changed it to indexOf/lastIndexOf, but there is no noticeable improvement as people mentioned in [19486077](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486077/java-fastest-way-to-read-through-text-file-with-2-million-lines). Someone else in the same thread mentioned to use Threads, but is this a right approach in my case?

Here is a snippet of the raw data:

```
5317:
2354291,3,2005-07-05
185150,2,2005-07-05
868399,3,2005-07-05
```

Above means:

```
[item_id]:
[user_id],[rating],[date]
[user_id],[rating],[date]
[user_id],[rating],[date]
```

Comment: MySQL has native support for loading text files into a database table, and it's usually much faster than writing code with insert statements: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html Perhaps you'd be better suited to transform the file into a format that can be loaded into MySQL via LOAD DATA INFILE. It's faster in my experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you have `AUTO_INCREMENT` `PRIMARY KEY` on those tables, beware that `INSERT IGNORE` will burn ids like crazy.
- "Batch" the inserts.  If you collect 100-1000 rows, build a single INSERT with those rows, then execute the statement, the INSERTion will run 10 times as fast.
- Don't try to batch 23,000 rows at once, you are likely to run into some problems (hard to predict what problems).
- On the other hand, if you can do `LOAD DATA` against those files, you can get rid of all your parsing code!  And it will run at least as fast as Batched inserts.

Comment: I went for the LOAD DATA approach. At least 60% faster now! Thank you!