# C - printf output varies depending on subsequent code

Tags: c, file, sockets, while-loop, strcat

**Preface**: I am just engaging C, so forgive my incompetence. The cause of this problem is probably basic.

**Problem**: I am trying to read a file and serve it over http with a socket. For some reason, the `printf` output of a previously read file varies depending on how much of the subsequent code is included.

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>


int main()
{

    // open a file to serve
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("index.html", "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open file.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Get file content
    char file_content[1024];
    if (fgets(file_content, 1024, file) != NULL)
    {

        fclose(file);

        // Add header to file content
        char http_header[2048] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\n";    
        strncat(http_header, file_content, 1028);

        // This output varies depending on inclusion of proceeding code.
        printf("%s", http_header);

        // create a socket
        int server_socket;
        server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);        

        // define the address
        struct sockaddr_in server_address;
        server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server_address.sin_port = htons(8001);
        server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

        bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));        
        listen(server_socket, 1);

        int client_socket;        
        while (1)
        {
            client_socket = accept(server_socket, NULL, NULL);
            send(client_socket, http_header, sizeof(http_header), 0);
            close(client_socket);
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

If I comment out everything past the `printf` statement, I get this intended output..

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

<html><body>Hi</body></html>
```

But if I run all the code, I get this instead..

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

If I can improve my question at all, please let me know how. Thank you.

Comment: O/T move `fclose(file);` and `return 0;` to outside of the `if(fgets(..))` check. Those things should happen whether `fgets` returns NULL or not.

Comment: I suspect your file content does not include a trailing `\n` character, and your program does not terminate because of the infinite loop, so the output buffer never gets flushed. Either exit the infinite loop, or add a trailing newline character to your output.

Comment: ... or try an `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf`.  `printf` is line-buffered, `fflush(stdout);` will manually flush `stdout`.

Comment: Your string `"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\n"` should be `"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n"` -- every line needs to end with `\r\n`.  However, that is unlikely to be your immediate problem.

Comment: The header should be generated before the loop; the content of the file should be echoed inside the loop.  The listen/accept code is oddly placed; shouldn't that be outside the loop and you only send the file when a connection is received?

Answer (score 1):

Mark Benningfield and Yano helped me understand the problem, thanks so much to both of you.

When you execute `printf()`, instead of the string going directly into the terminal window, each line goes into a [buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648309/what-does-it-mean-by-buffer).

Each line in the buffer must be *flushed* for them to show in the terminal. The buffer can be *automatically* flushed by [these events](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Flushing-Buffers.html)

Strings ending in `\n` are automatically flushed, this is why the first line `HTTP/1.1 200 OK \r\n\n` displays fine. The second line `<html><body>hi</body></html>` does not end with a `\n`, or trigger any other automatic flush events, so it does not display.

*Usually* this is not a problem because when the program terminates, the buffer is automatically flushed, and all lines that entered the buffer through `printf` show up in the terminal. Since my program at the bottom enters an infinite while loop, the program never terminates, and the buffer is never flushed.

Calling `fflush(stdout)` after `printf` forces a write of `stdout`'s entire buffer.

[More info on fflush](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fflush.htm)

Comment: Note that the line buffering settings may vary amongst implementations, you are just describing how yours works by default

Comment: "Strings ending in \n are automatically flushed" --> Not quite.  It depends on [What are the rules of automatic flushing stdout buffer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39536212/2410359)