# Understanding Buffering using memset()

Tags: c, buffer, memset

There are a few questions on here about how to use memset() in C or what a buffer is. But I have yet to find a good explanation for why it is necessary to use and what it actually does for your program.

I saw in this program that was trying to print out a rotating 3D cube that they used. I am struggling to see what this actually does for the program.

```
memset(buffer, backgroundASCIICode, width * height);
```

Would love any help trying to explain what a buffer is, and how memset() is used to create one.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: A buffer is basically some chunk of memory that is accessible by the application, so it lives somewhere on the stack or heap. The `memset` function basically sets some number of bytes to some value (often zero, but `backgroundASCIICode`) here. Typical use of a buffer is to allow for (temporary) storage of some value. Many C functions or library functions ask the user to provide a buffer, this is another way of knowing that the function is likely not going to allocate memory itself, it trusts the user to provide something it can use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does it mean by buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648309/what-does-it-mean-by-buffer)

Answer (score 1):

`memset` is a C-standard function from `string.h` with the prototype:

`memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);`

It takes a pointer to a memory location, or *buffer*, in the form of `void *s`, a 1-byte value in the form of `int c`, and a number of bytes to be set in the form of `size_t n`.

The function writes the value in `c` into `n`-bytes starting at the memory address `s`

For instance the code snippet:

```
int *array = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
memset(array, 0, 10 * sizeof(int));
```

...allocates a *buffer* large enough for 10 `int`s, and then writes zeroes in every byte in that *buffer*.

In the example you give, `backgroundASCIICode` is being copied into `width * height` bytes beginning at the pointer `buffer`.

Generally speaking a *buffer* is any memory region that you have access to via a pointer to the first byte, which is why `memset` takes a pointer to the buffer via a `void*`, since it doesn't care what *kind* of data is stored there, since it's just going to overwrite each byte.

Answer (score 1):

The `memset` function is used to set all bytes in a particular block of memory to a given value.

Here, a "buffer" is just some arbitrary block of memory, i.e. a single variable, array, `struct`, or any combination thereof.  `memset` doesn't create a buffer, but rather modifies the values in it.

In this particular case, `buffer` is the start of some piece of memory already in use, whose size in bytes is at least `width * height`, and all of those bytes are set to the value of `backgroundASCIICode`.